# AngularJS: how to make this ticker animation continuous and dynamically get element dimensions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css

This is my first AngularJS attempt, and I'm building a ticker of boxes

## [CodePen Here](http://codepen.io/ajf-/pen/cErAy/)

### Code:

#### index.jade:

```
doctype html
html(ng-app="ticker")
    head
        script(src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js", type="text/javascript")
        script(src="script.js")
        link(rel="stylesheet", href="css.css")
body
    div(ng-controller="tickerCtrl")

        .ticker
            .viewport(ng-class="{moving: moving}", ng-click="moveLeft()")
                .box(ng-repeat="box in boxes")
                    span {{ box.title }}

        button(type="button", ng-click="moveLeft()") &lt; Move left
```

#### script.js

```
angular.module('ticker', [])
    .controller('tickerCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {
        $scope.boxes = [
            {title: 'Box 1'},
            {title: 'Box 2'},
            {title: 'Box 3'},
            {title: 'Box 4'},
            {title: 'Box 5'},
            {title: 'Box 6'},
            {title: 'Box 7'},
            {title: 'Box 8'},
            {title: 'Box 9'},
            {title: 'Box 10'}
        ];
        $scope.moving = false;

        $scope.moveLeft = function() {
            $scope.moving = true;
            $window.setTimeout($scope.switchFirst, 2000);
        };
        $scope.switchFirst = function() {
            $scope.boxes.push($scope.boxes.shift());
            $scope.moving = false;
            $scope.$apply();
        };
    }]);
```

#### css.less

```
.ticker {
    width: 90%;
    padding: 1em 1em;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;

    .viewport {
        &.moving {
            animation: moveLeft 1 2s linear;
        }

        position: absolute;
        height: 100px;

        border-width: 1px 0;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #cccccc;

        white-space: nowrap;

        .box {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100%;

            border: 1px solid #eee;
            margin: 0 5px;

            text-align: center;
        }
    }
}

@keyframes moveLeft {
    0% { transform: translateX(0) }
    100% { transform: translateX(-110px) }
}
```

### I'm running into the following problems:

- How can I make the movement continuous ? When I try adding `$window.setInterval($scope.moveLeft, 2000);` inside `tickerCtrl`, the animation is applied only the first time.
- How can I dynamically get element dimensions? Currently, the viewport shifts `110px` left, but that should be the value of the first element's `outerWidth` (in jQuery lingo).
- Is this even a correct application for AngularJS or should I switch to jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: check out my solution - http://cdpn.io/rlgve

First, with Angular, do not use setTimeout. Use Angular's $timeout.

Second, if you want it repeated, you can use setInterval instead, or in Angular, $interval.

Angular uses lighter-weight jquery-like code for dom maniuplation called JQlite, and you don't need jQuery in addition to it. You can access DOM elements using $element.

Or the javascript DOM API...

`document.body.getElementsByClassName('some-class')[0].clientWidth`

Comment: I'm using $interval here: http://codepen.io/ajf-/pen/sICDr/, but the same thing is happening: it's only applied correctly the first time. Any ideas?

Comment: check out my solution above